# Spark: sort the list by string

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

In the below code I am able to arrange the list by "sortByKey".
 However, requirement is to sort by string in alphabetical orders.

That is expected output should be:

```
Array((3,book),(2,cat),(7,cup),(5,heater),(6,mouse),(1,screen),(4,tv))
```

```
scala> val randRDD = sc.parallelize(List( (2,"cat"), (6, "mouse"),(7, "cup"), (3, "book"), (4, "tv"), (1, "screen"), (5, "heater")), 3)
randRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> randRDD.collect
res0: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((2,cat), (6,mouse), (7,cup), (3,book), (4,tv), (1,screen), (5,heater))

scala> randRDD.sortByKey().collect
res1: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((1,screen), (2,cat), (3,book), (4,tv), (5,heater), (6,mouse), (7,cup))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortBy` as

```
randRDD.sortBy(_._2).collect
//res2: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((3,book), (2,cat), (7,cup), (5,heater), (6,mouse), (1,screen), (4,tv))
```

or

Just *use two swappings*, *one before sortByKey* and *another after sortByKey*

```
randRDD.map(_.swap).sortByKey().map(_.swap).collect
//res2: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((3,book), (2,cat), (7,cup), (5,heater), (6,mouse), (1,screen), (4,tv))
```